# UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

When I was building an app in XCode 4, I was had the following code that worked fine:

```
TestClass *tester = [[TestClass alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *nsa = [NSMutableArray array];
[nsa insertObject:tester atIndex:0];
self.navcontroller.viewControllers = nsa;
self.navcontroller.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:self.navcontroller];
self.parentcontroller.viewControllers = array;

[tester release];
```

However, now when I run this code in XCode 5, I receive the following error:

```
UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!
```

I understand iOS7 can now not have nested Navigation Controllers, but how would I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue.
We have the main flow of the app managed by a `UINavigationViewController` (a class that inherits from `UINavigationViewController`).

Our app has many different processes that can be aborted at any time. Each of these processes are managed by their own `UINavigationViewController` (other 
classes that inherit ...) so we can pop the entire process when user aborts it.

In order to overcome the limitation of pushing a `UINavigationViewController` into the stack of another `UINavigationViewController` we do this idea:

```
NavVC1 : The main UINavigationViewController<br>
NavVC2 : A UINavigationViewController I want to push somewhere into NavVC1 stack<br>
VC_Host : An empty UIViewController containing NavVC2 as a child view controller.
```

We push VC_Host into NavVC1 stack and we get a nested `UINavigationViewController`.

Comment: so your saying it IS possible to have navigation controller nested in a navigation controller?

Comment: because i've been trying to implement this for a while

Comment: Yes, you need a UIVIewController as a parent of the nested UINavigationViewController.
Then push the UIViewController to the outer UINavigationViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you were ever supposed to have nested `UINavigationController`s, and even if you could before, there's little reason to do so. You can present a `UINavigationController` as a modal view from another view controller that is already in a `UINavigationController`, but containing one in another just doesn't make any sense. That's why it's not allowed.

If you wanted to nest one within another, for whatever reason, you could probably find a third party open source `UINavigationController` replacement that isn't a subclass of `UINavigationController` itself, but instead uses the view controller containment methods on its own to duplicate the behavior, and then you should be able to nest those. But you have to be sure that it's not a `UINavigationController` subclass or it'll still restrict you in the same way.

My ultimate suggestion though is to rethink your UI so that you don't have to try nesting `UINavigationController`s. I can't see a good use case for this.

Comment: There are occasions when this might make sense, especially when you're dealing with more screen real estate like iPad.